# GAE datastore JOIN + GROUP BY

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I had posted this here and was asked to move it to code review since my code works and am looking for the best possible solution : [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21998312/gae-datastore-join-group-by/21998313#21998313)

**NOTE:** I have seen the JOIN in GAE related posts but GROUP BY in my requirements made me make a new post and I have made a solution of my own which I wanted to check how good is it.

---

**Datastore Entities properties and types (database)**

1. **Entity** : PartyEntity *let's call this as a*

   - String partyName
   - String partyId
   - BlobKey image
2. **Entity** : InsertEntity *let's call this as b*

   - String partyIdentifier
   - String name
   - String constituency

---

**Objective**

```sql
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b on a.partyId = b.partyIdentifier GROUP BY b.constituency;
```

---

The solution I made is as follows.  Do suggest any changes or better ideas.

```
// SELECT * FROM a (PartyEntity holds unique partyId) and for each partyId SELECT * FROM b

private List<ListDisplay> initData() {

    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
            .getDatastoreService();

    List<ListDisplay> data = new ArrayList<ListDisplay>();

    Query query = new Query("PartyEntity");
    PreparedQuery preparedQuery = datastore.prepare(query);
    List<Entity> entities = preparedQuery.asList(FetchOptions.Builder
            .withDefaults());

    for (Entity entity : entities) {

        String PARTY_ID = (String) entity.getProperty("partyId");

        // fetch from another
        Query query2 = new Query("InsertEntity");
        Filter filterByPartyId = new Query.FilterPredicate(
                "partyIdentifier", FilterOperator.EQUAL, PARTY_ID);
        query2.setFilter(filterByPartyId);
        PreparedQuery preparedQuery2 = datastore.prepare(query2);

        List<Entity> entities2 = preparedQuery2.asList(FetchOptions.Builder
                    .withDefaults());

        for (Entity entity2 : entities2) {
            ListDisplay display = new ListDisplay();
            display.setPartyId((String) entity.getProperty("partyId"));
            display.setPartyName((String) entity.getProperty("partyName"));
            display.setImage((BlobKey) entity.getProperty("image"));
            display.setName((String) entity2.getProperty("name"));
            display.setConstituency((String) entity2
                    .getProperty("constituency"));
            data.add(display);
        } // end loop entity2

    } // end loop entity

    return data;
}
```

---

```
// GROUP BY constituency clause part

public HashMap<String, List<ListDisplay>> getData() {
    HashMap<String, List<ListDisplay>> data = new HashMap<>();
    List<ListDisplay> list = initData();

    for (ListDisplay d : list) {
        // if null add
        if (data.get(d.getConstituency()) == null) {
            List<ListDisplay> internal = new ArrayList<>();
            internal.add(d);
            data.put(d.getConstituency(), internal);
        }
        // else modify
        else {
            List<ListDisplay> hashlist = data.get(d.getConstituency());
            hashlist.add(d);
            data.remove(d.getConstituency());
            data.put(d.getConstituency(), hashlist);
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few generic notes, I'm not familiar with Google App Engine:

1. `HashMap<...>` reference types could be `Map<...>`:

   ```
   public Map<String, List<ListDisplay>> getData() {
   ```

   See: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 52: Refer to objects by their interfaces*
2. I'd rename this variable to `result` to express its purpose:

   > ```
   > List<ListDisplay> data = new ArrayList<ListDisplay>();
   > ```
3. `remove` is unnecesary here, put will override it:

   > ```
   > data.remove(d.getConstituency());
   > data.put(d.getConstituency(), hashlist);
   > ```
4. Consider replacing the following with a `Multimap`:

   > ```
   > // if null add
   > if (data.get(d.getConstituency()) == null) {
   >     List<ListDisplay> internal = new ArrayList<>();
   >     internal.add(d);
   >     data.put(d.getConstituency(), internal);
   > }
   > // else modify
   > else {
   >     List<ListDisplay> hashlist = data.get(d.getConstituency());
   >     hashlist.add(d);
   >     data.remove(d.getConstituency());
   >     data.put(d.getConstituency(), hashlist);
   > }
   > ```

   The following uses [Google Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [`Multimap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) and much simpler:

   ```
   final ArrayListMultimap<String, ListDisplay> data = ArrayListMultimap.create();

   for (ListDisplay d : list) {
       data.put(d.getConstituency(), d);
   }
   ```

   If you really need `Map` return type you can convert it  back to `Map` with `data.asMap()` which returns a `Map<String, Collection<ListDisplay>>` but you cast it down safely to `Map<String, List<ListDisplay>>`. ([`ArrayListMultimap` javadoc supports this](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html#asMap%28%29) as well as [these Stack Overflow posts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11204143/843804).)
5. Variable names in Java usually `camelCase`.

   > ```
   > String PARTY_ID = (String) entity.getProperty("partyId");
   > ```
6. Comments on the closing curly braces are unnecessary and disturbing. Modern IDEs and editors could show blocks.

   ```
       } // end loop entity2
   ```

   [“// …” comments at end of code block after } - good or bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/53274/36726)